How to recover the vector $x$ when multiplying it with a matrix $A$ that has a specific structure
I have the matrix with specific structure as below:
$$A = \left[ \begin{matrix}
 a &  -b&  -c& d \\
b &  e&  -d&  -f \\
c &  -d&  a&  -b \\
d &  f& b & e
\end{matrix} \right]$$
I am asking, what are the characteristics of the matrix $A$? For example, assuming that $y = Ax$ where $x$ is a vector, is it possible to recover the vector $x$ with less computational complexity?
Additionally, if I have know that summation of the matrix $A$ gives a well known vector $h$, I mean the summation of rows of the matrix $A$ gives a well-known vector $h$, can that reduce the complexity or offer a way to calculate the vector $x$ with less complexity?
EDIT
The matrix $A$ has complex values, also $x$ is a complex-value vector.

The matrix is composed of submatrices of the form $\begin{bmatrix}u & -v \\ v & u\end{bmatrix}$, for example $\begin{bmatrix}a & -c \\ c & a\end{bmatrix}$ is in the first and the third rows and columns. These matrices all commute and can be simultaneously diagonalized: we have $\begin{bmatrix}u & -v \\ v & u\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix} = (u - iv) \begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}$, $\begin{bmatrix}u & -v \\ v & u\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix} = (u + iv) \begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$, so after the basis change to $\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$ the matrix is $\begin{bmatrix}u - iv & 0\\0 & u + iv\end{bmatrix}$. For computational reasons it's better to use the basis $\frac12\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}, \frac12\begin{bmatrix}1\\-i\end{bmatrix}$, so that a vector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}$ is transformed to $\begin{bmatrix}x'\\y'\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}x -iy \\ x + iy\end{bmatrix}$. The diagonalized matrix is of course still the same.
In our matrix we have $4$ submatrices like this, so the equation $$\begin{bmatrix}a & -b & -c & d \\ b & e & -d & -f \\ c & -d & a & -b \\ d & f & b & e\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\t\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}p\\q\\r\\s\end{bmatrix}$$ after the basis change to $\frac12\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\i\\0\end{bmatrix}, \frac12\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\i\end{bmatrix}, \frac12\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\-i\\0\end{bmatrix}, \frac12\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-i\end{bmatrix}$ translates to a block diagonal system
$$\begin{bmatrix}a - ic & -(b - id) & 0 & 0 \\ b - id & e - if & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & a + ic & -(b + id) \\ 0 & 0 & b + id & e + if\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x - iz \\ y - it \\ x + iz \\ y + it\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}p - ir \\ q - is \\ p + ir \\ q + is\end{bmatrix},$$
we only need to solve two $2 \times 2$ systems and then find $x,y,z,t$, for example, $x = \frac{(x + iz) + (x - iz)}{2}$.

What's about if the matrix $A$ has complex values? Sorry, I forgot to mention that matrix $A$ has complex values.

I edited so that it works for complex numbers.

Thank you so much, I will try to generalize that suggestions for bigger matrices with same structure, and  feedback you

I think the last equation is block diagonal matrix where each block has same structure of the main matrix, can it also be simplified to have diagonal matrix ?

No, for this we would need $a = e$ and $c = f$.

Assuming $a = e$ and $c = f$, how that matrix will be also simplified?

Then I believe it will be diagonal in the basis $(1, \alpha i, \beta i, -\alpha\beta)$ where $\alpha, \beta = \pm 1$

Could you please  add the details to the answer? What will be the vector $x$ in that case ?
